# JS Dialog that asks the user to share, "message" parameter does nothing?

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, dialog

Here is the example:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

It's supposed to do a popup with the message "Facebook Dialogs are so easy!" But when I go to the url, the textarea is empty. Thus proving itself wrong.

How do you make a dialog box when the message entered already, so the user can just click share without typing anything?

Try it yourself:
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=123050457758183&link=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&name=Facebook%20Dialogs&caption=Reference%20Documentation&description=Dialogs%20provide%20a%20simple,%20consistent%20interface%20for%20applications%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&message=Facebook%20Dialogs%20are%20so%20easy!&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook recently removed this functionality, so it is no longer possible. The `message` parameter is now ignored. You can thank spammers for that.

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/510/

Sorry.

---

There is also a note about this in the [Feed Dialog API docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/):

> `message`
>   **This field will be ignored on July 12, 2011** The message to prefill the text field that the user will type in. To be compliant with Facebook Platform Policies, your application may only set this field if the user manually generated the content earlier in the workflow. Most applications should not set this.

Comment: Thanks Matt. It's been like this for over a month I think. They should put a comments box on their doc pages so people can tell others what doesn't work anymore since they don't update their docs.